# sql - get one record if duplicate

Tags: sql

For example I have a table like this.

```
+----+------+
| id | type |
+----+------+
| 1  |  I   |
| 2  |  E   |
| 4  |  I   |
| 4  |  E   |
| 5  |  E   |
| 6  |  E   |
| 7  |  E   |
| 8  |  E   |
| 8  |  I   |
+----+------+
```

I want to return distinct id, and if 'I' and 'E' both appear use 'I'

```
+----+------+
| id | type |
+----+------+
| 1  |  I   |
| 2  |  E   |
| 4  |  I   |
| 5  |  E   |
| 6  |  E   |
| 7  |  E   |
| 8  |  I   |
+----+------+
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is this sampe data or real data?

Comment: Also, what version of SQL are you using?  This might determine whether the answers already given are valid or not.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I need to support both pl-sql and t-sql.

Comment: Juergen's solution should work fine for T-SQL based on what I read.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Juergen's solution work on Oracle (pl-sql) too. Just tested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group by the `id` and use `max()` to get `I` since `I` is greather than `E` alphabetically

```
select id, max(type) as type
from your_table
group by id
```

Comment: I will mark this as answer for now because it works for me. But I really want to know a more generic way. If type is more then 2, and I want to the one in the middle.

Comment: A solution for that depends on the DB engine you use. And you would have to define an order of the types to be returned (which one is first, second and third).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt at a more general solution which doesn't rely on using the lexographic ordering of the letters.  It explicitly computes the count of occurrences of each `I` and `E` in each `id` group.  When both letters occur together, it chooses `I`, otherwise it chooses the appropriate letter.

```
SELECT t.id AS 'id', CASE WHEN SUM(t.case_i) > 0 AND SUM(t.case_e) > 0 THEN 'I'
                          WHEN SUM(t.case_i) > 0 THEN 'I'
                          WHEN SUM(t.case_e) > 0 THEN 'E'
                      ELSE NULL
                      END AS 'type'
FROM
(
    SELECT id, type,
        CASE WHEN type='I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS case_i
        CASE WHEN type='E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS case_e
    FROM your_table
) t
GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I think this is much better since it fit in any case.